# After update non-english characters not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, input

I recently updated Ubuntu from 16 to 18.04 and after that I can't input non-engilsh characters in any application. Funny thing is that I can type them on Ubuntu search, but can't in webbrowsers/chats/etc. I tried with dbus reinstallation, switching locale to English and back to mine and still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally fixed it.

I haven't done any changes in keyboard settings before and after update - but still for some reason I had "alt" set as shortcut to maximize window... Changing it in keyboard settings enabled non-english characters for me.